# Is there a way to know if Topics is Enabled for a specific Object?

Tags: apex, chatter, topics

Is there a way to know if Topics is Enabled for a specific Object?, I need to verify this for case as precondition to the instalallation of a package.
If someone can tell me how to enable it in apex is good too.

Answer (score 0):

You can Know whether topic enabled or not by just searching for "Topics for Objects" in Quick find/Search box.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation you pulled this from and quote it? It's unlikely to answer the OP's question (they seem to want a programmatic approach), but as written its length is short enough it's getting flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

TopicsForObjects metadata representing the settings what you looking for.
You can use https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi library for querying metadata in apex.